# VsHub failed to locate/start service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, diagnostic-tools

When I start visual studio and debug aplication and open Diagnostic tool, I get the following message: The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly.

When I open Output window for Diagnostic Hub, I see this message:
**VsHub failed to locate/start service.**

Any idea, how can I force diagnostic tool to start working?
From windows services I can see that "Visual Studio Standard Collector Service"
is started with "Local System Account" and Visual studio is started with "Run as administrator".

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS didn't address the issue?  Try disabling your anti-virus and see if that makes a difference.  VsHub might be falsely identified as malware by some of the antivirus apps (such as Avast)

Answer (score 0):

My error message is

> The diagnostic tools failed unexpectedly. The Diagnostic Hub output in the Output window may contain additional information.

Try to modify the Environment Variable `TEMP` as following rules and reopen Visual Studio. That works for me, maybe it also works for you. My IDE is Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Update 3.

It must only one path in `TEMP`. For example,

Fail:`%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp;C:\OTHER_PATH`
 Fail: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\;C:\OTHER_PATH`
 Pass: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp`